# phonegap filetransfer to upload picture to server

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, phonegap-plugins

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> HellowWorld PhoneGap App </title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
alert("Ready ");
}

function capture(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    }); 
}

var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = imageData;
    var blob = image[0].getAsFile();
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var file = blob;
    upload(file);


function uploadImage(file){

    

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("file", file);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', 'uploads/upload.php', true);
        xhr.send(fd);

    }

function onUploadSuccess(){
    alert('Photo Uploaded Successfully');
}

function onUploadError(){
    alert('Error uploading photo');
}

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = imageData;
    uploadImage(imageData);
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
  

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload images to remote server</h1>

<div class="app">
<h4><a href="#" onclick="capture();">Select an Image</a></h4>
<img id="myImage" src="" width="50%">
</div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php

$destination = 'uploads/';

if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {

    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

    //echo $name;
    //echo $tmp_name;
    //echo $error;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destination.$name);

}

?>
```

so i tried creating a phonegap app to upload pictures to the server. i first created a upload folder and pasted the upload.php there. the javascript and html is index.html. i tried running, it allows me to take and view the picture but there is an error in uploading the picture. how come? what have i wrote wrong?

```php
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
?>
```

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  alert("Ready ");
}

function capture() {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
  });
}


function uploadImage(imageData) {
  var serverURL = "localhost:3000/uploads/upload.php";
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileKey = 'file';
  options.fileName = imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

  var ft = new FileTransfer();
  ft.upload(imageData, serverURL, onUploadSuccess, onUploadError, options);
}

function onUploadSuccess() {
  alert('Photo Uploaded Successfully');
}

function onUploadError() {
  alert('Error uploading photo');
}

function onSuccess(imageData) {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  image.src = imageData;
  uploadImage(imageData);
}

function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title> HellowWorld PhoneGap App </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Upload images to remote server</h1>

  <div class="app">
    <h4><a href="#" onclick="capture();">Select an Image</a></h4>
    <img id="myImage" src="" width="50%">

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What error, please be specific

Comment: @RiggsFolly

function onUploadError() {
  alert('Error uploading photo');
}

this error

Comment: Are you building for android?

Answer (score 0):

in first you need to use isset like below, to avoid certain mistakes:

```
<?php

$destination = './data/test/';

if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {

    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

    //echo $name;
    //echo $tmp_name;
    //echo $error;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destination.$name);

}

?>
```

and use this upload function :

```
function upload(file){

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("file", file);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);
        xhr.send(fd);

    }
```

to get your image and before the call of the upload function you can use this :

```
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  image.src = imageData;
  var blob = image[0].getAsFile();
  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  var file = blob;
  upload(file);
```

Comment: i tried that upload function and now i cant click to select image as well

Comment: you need to convert the imageData before call the upload function

Comment: i have edited it, now i am able to select the image, but its still not uploading, and when selected the image shows error

Comment: as you can see ive pasted the updated code snippet above.